# What is our stance on questions aiming at finding official documents about companies (assume the question isn't specific to just one company)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope

What is our stance on questions aiming at finding official documents about companies/stocks (assume the question isn't specific to just one company)? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

I see that sometimes such questions get closed, sometimes not:

- [Where can I find filings for OTC stocks?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/102313/5656)
- [How to find a public company's balance sheet and income statement?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/77666/5656)
- [Where can I find ADR (American depositary receipts) prospectuses? [closed]](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121360/5656)

so I'm confused regarding the scope.

Comment: I would like to invite a few of the close voters (including those who voted “leave closed” in the review queue) to explain how the ADR question is off-topic.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica Since you're the one who voted “leave closed” in the review queue, could you please explain your vote, despite the fact that it seems similar questions are opened and upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we seem to have a culture on our site for closing questions as “product or service recommendation” (shopping questions) that are not really seeking product recommendations at all.

See meta question [“What is meant by the off-topic close reason “product or service recommendations”?”](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2207/10997). Your question [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121360/10997) is a “How do I find this information?” question, which is not seeking a product or service recommendation. If you had asked something like “Which blog has the best reviews of ADRs?” or “Which broker has the most information on ADRs on their website?”, I could see why it should be closed. But asking how to find information should be on-topic.

[Your question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121360/10997) should not have been closed. I have voted to reopen.