# Are questions about using financial software on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I have a technical question about the functionality of the financial site Mint. Specifically, I want to ask whether it is possible to use Mint to schedule monthly recurring payments to a personal bank account.

Are questions about the functionality of financial software permitted? Or would that be off-topic?

Comment: Related: [Should questions on the technical usage of a financial management tool be on-topic, or off-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/10997)

Comment: @BenMiller - are you voting to close as duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Help section -

If you have a question about:

Saving, Investing, & Trading

[Use of software for managing one's finances. Not recommendations, just questions regarding specific software](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Therefore, on topic.